# How to convert Int to Varchar

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I tried to convert Int to Varchar but I'm unable to get output. Can anyone suggest any other way to do so?

I have below query and need to cast `StoreNo` (`int`) to a `varchar`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getrevenue]
    @date1 DATE,
    @date2 DATE,
    @StoreNo NVARCHAR(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_test NVARCHAR(max)

    --SET @StoreNo='68,78,104'
    SET @sql_test = 'SELECT t1.transtoreno AS StoreNO
            ,t3.NAME AS NAME
            ,t1.Dealdate AS DATE
            ,t1.UKEI AS UKEI
            ,t2.SubTotal AS SubTotal
            ,ISNULL(t2.SubTotalDiscount, 0) AS SubToatlDiscount
            ,ISNULL(t1.twoeyesSubtotalDiscount, 0) AS TwoeyeSubTotalDiscount
            ,t2.ValueInquiries AS TotalDiscount
            ,t2.NetSale AS Netsale
            ,t2.TotalSale AS ToatlSale
            ,t2.Cash AS Cash
            ,ISNULL(t2.GiftVochuer, 0) AS GiftVochuer
            ,ISNULL(t2.Card, 0) AS Card
            ,ISNULl(t2.Suica, 0) AS Suica
            ,t2.WONPOINT AS WAONPOINT
            ,t1.TaxExemption AS TAXExemption
            ,t2.TaxTotal AS TaxTotal
            ,t2.Returngoods AS Returngoods
            ,t2.Regiminus AS RegiMinus
            ,t2.PrintRecipt AS printrecipt
            ,ISNULL(t1.Visitorcount, 0) AS VisitorCount
        FROM (
            SELECT CAST(StoreNo AS NVARCHAR) AS transtoreno
                ,(DealDate) AS Dealdate
                ,SUM(SalePrice) AS UKEI
                ,SUM(TansuNebikiPrice) AS twoeyesdicount
                ,SUM(SubTotalNebiki2Price) AS twoeyesSubtotalDiscount
                ,SUM(TotalSalePrice - Si1Tax - RegiMinusNo) AS Netsale
                ,SUM(SpecialConsumptionTaxPrice) AS TaxExemption
                ,Sum(RegiMinusNo) AS Receiptissue
                ,SUM(VisitorCount) AS Visitorcount
            FROM POS_TtlTran
            GROUP BY StoreNo
                ,DealDate
            ) t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DATE AS D
                ,cast(StoreNo AS NVARCHAR) AS s
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 23
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Cash
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 31
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Card
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 30
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS GiftVochuer
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 138
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Returngoods
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 160
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS PrintRecipt
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 304
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Suica
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 26
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS WONPOINT
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 139
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Regiminus
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 4
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS SubToTal
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 7
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS SubTotalDiscount
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 8
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS TwoeyesubTotalDiscount
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 18
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS ValueInquiries
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 22
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS TotalSale
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 114
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS TaxTotal
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 2
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS NetSale
            FROM POS_FinTtl
            GROUP BY StoreNo
                ,DATE
            ) t2 ON t1.transtoreno = t2.s
            AND t1.Dealdate = t2.D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT StoreNo AS No
                ,StoreName AS NAME
            FROM Store
            ) t3 ON t2.s = t3.No
        WHERE (
                t1.transtoreno IN (''' 
                + CAST(@StoreNo AS NVARCHAR(max)) + ''') 
                AND (t1.Dealdate between ''' + CAST(@date1 AS VARCHAR(30)) + ''' 
                AND ''' + CAST(@date2 AS VARCHAR(30)) + '''))'
END
```

Comment: Seems to me this is a database design issue. If they are numbers then change the schema and make them INT data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this one will work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getrevenue] @date1 DATE
    ,@date2 DATE
    ,@StoreNo NVARCHAR(max) `
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_test NVARCHAR(max)

    --SET @StoreNo='68,78,104'
    SET @sql_test ='SELECT t1.transtoreno AS StoreNO
            ,t3.NAME AS NAME
            ,t1.Dealdate AS DATE
            ,t1.UKEI AS UKEI
            ,t2.SubTotal AS SubTotal
            ,ISNULL(t2.SubTotalDiscount, 0) AS SubToatlDiscount
            ,ISNULL(t1.twoeyesSubtotalDiscount, 0) AS TwoeyeSubTotalDiscount
            ,t2.ValueInquiries AS TotalDiscount
            ,t2.NetSale AS Netsale
            ,t2.TotalSale AS ToatlSale
            ,t2.Cash AS Cash
            ,ISNULL(t2.GiftVochuer, 0) AS GiftVochuer
            ,ISNULL(t2.Card, 0) AS Card
            ,ISNULl(t2.Suica, 0) AS Suica
            ,t2.WONPOINT AS WAONPOINT
            ,t1.TaxExemption AS TAXExemption
            ,t2.TaxTotal AS TaxTotal
            ,t2.Returngoods AS Returngoods
            ,t2.Regiminus AS RegiMinus
            ,t2.PrintRecipt AS printrecipt
            ,ISNULL(t1.Visitorcount, 0) AS VisitorCount
        FROM (
            SELECT CAST(StoreNo AS NVARCHAR) AS transtoreno
                ,(DealDate) AS Dealdate
                ,SUM(SalePrice) AS UKEI
                ,SUM(TansuNebikiPrice) AS twoeyesdicount
                ,SUM(SubTotalNebiki2Price) AS twoeyesSubtotalDiscount
                ,SUM(TotalSalePrice - Si1Tax - RegiMinusNo) AS Netsale
                ,SUM(SpecialConsumptionTaxPrice) AS TaxExemption
                ,Sum(RegiMinusNo) AS Receiptissue
                ,SUM(VisitorCount) AS Visitorcount
            FROM POS_TtlTran
            GROUP BY StoreNo
                ,DealDate
            ) t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT DATE AS D
                ,cast(StoreNo AS NVARCHAR) AS s
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 23
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Cash
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 31
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Card
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 30
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS GiftVochuer
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 138
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Returngoods
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 160
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS PrintRecipt
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 304
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Suica
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 26
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS WONPOINT
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 139
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS Regiminus
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 4
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS SubToTal
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 7
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS SubTotalDiscount
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 8
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS TwoeyesubTotalDiscount
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 18
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS ValueInquiries
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 22
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS TotalSale
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 114
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS TaxTotal
                ,SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN SerialNo LIKE 2
                            THEN DayTotalAmt
                        ELSE 0
                        END) AS NetSale
            FROM POS_FinTtl
            GROUP BY StoreNo
                ,DATE
            ) t2 ON t1.transtoreno = t2.s
            AND t1.Dealdate = t2.D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT StoreNo AS No
                ,StoreName AS NAME
            FROM Store
            ) t3 ON t2.s = t3.No
        WHERE (
                t1.transtoreno IN (''' 
                + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), @StoreNo) + ''') 
                AND (t1.Dealdate between ''' + CAST(@date1 AS VARCHAR(30)) + ''' 
                AND ''' + CAST(@date2 AS VARCHAR(30)) + '''))'

END
```

Comment: The wait operation timed out[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

Comment: sorry, I missed one line of code. It's not executing the dynamic query. Please add that line and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
where (t1.transtoreno IN (''' 
        + CAST(@StoreNo AS nvarchar(max)) + ''')
```

Should be

```
where (t1.transtoreno IN (''' 
        + replace(CAST(@StoreNo AS nvarchar(max)),',',''',''') + ''')
```